# ModalPopupExtender ASP MessageBox not closing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wanted a popup messagebox that would show something like "Done!" when the row in my gridview is successfully removed and something else if there is an error. I used ModalPopupExtender. The modal popup shows fine but it just keeps on the page even if I click the OK button. Here is my code:

ASP:

```
<!--ModalPopup for "Done" message-->
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtDone" runat="server" PopupControlID="donePanel" TargetControlID="donePanel" CancelControlID="donePanelBtn">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<div class="panel">
    <asp:Panel ID="donePanel" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="41px" 
            BackColor="#FF9900">
        <asp:Label ID="donePanelLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="donePanelBtn" runat="server" Text="OK" 
                onclick="donePanelBtn_Click"  />
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void GridViewDept_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    //some other code
    if (delSuccess)
    {
        donePanelLabel.Text = "Record deleted!";
        ModalPopupExtDone.Show();
        this.RefreshGridView();
    }
    else
    {
        donePanelLabel.Text = "Record not deleted! Please try again!";
        ModalPopupExtDone.Show();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did u write the code to close the Modalpopup on the donePanelBtn button click event.

Comment: @MahaSwetha Yes, I do. I write  ModalPopupExtDone.Hide(); but it doesnt have any effect

Comment: Try to make Div class and Modalpopupextender visiblity=false;

Comment: @MahaSwetha When I try your solution, the popup does not even show up.

Comment: Your Problem is to Modalpopup appears on page without closing right? I told for closing it.Place that code,when you want to close it.Please,let me know,if anything else is your problem.